# Python/Neo4j Query Optimization

Tags: python, neo4j, query-optimization

I have run out of ideas trying to find the cause for such low write speeds. My background is relational databases so I might be doing something wrong. To add 10 nodes and 45 connections I currently need 1.4 seconds (empty DB). This is unacceptable and in my opinion should be order of milliseconds if even.

**Requirement**

Create method to add **snapshots** to the Neo4j database. One snapshot consists of 10 nodes (all have different labels and properties). I need to connect all nodes in this snapshot, unidirectionally, and without recursive connections. This equates to 10 nodes 45 connections per snapshot. Relationships are created with property strength = 1. Every time I add a new relationship, if it already exists (meaning `match nodeA(oHash) -> nodeB(oHash)`) I just increment the strength instead of having duplicates.

**Measurements**

I compensated for all overhead with regards to the API, Python itself, etc. Currently over **99.9%** of the execution time is from querying Neo4j. I observed that generating nodes seems to be much slower than generating the connections (**about ~90%** of the total time).

To generate one snapshot (10 nodes, 45 connections) into an empty database my query (from Python) takes **1.4 seconds** when averaged on **100 runs**.

**Indexes**

In the code I am going to show in the post, below, you will find a create constraints method that I never call. This is because I already created the indexes on all node/label types and I removed the call to it to reduce overhead of checking on existing indexes. Every node has an "oHash" property which is an MD5 hash of the json of all properties excluding internal Neo4j <ID>. This uniquely identifies my nodes so I created a UNIQUE constraint on "oHash". As far as I understand creating a UNIQUE constraint also creates an index on that property in Neo4j.

**Best Practices**

I used all recommended best practices I could find online. These include:

1. Creating a single driver instance and reusing it
2. Creating a single driver session and reusing it
3. Using explicit transactions
4. Using query parameters
5. Creating a batch and executing as a single transaction

**Implementation**

Here is my current implementation:

```
import json
import hashlib
import uuid
from neo4j import GraphDatabase

class SnapshotRepository:
    """A repository to handle snapshots in a Neo4j database."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize a connection to the Neo4j database."""
        with open("config.json", "r") as file:
            config = json.load(file)
        self._driver = GraphDatabase.driver(
            config["uri"], auth=(config["username"], config["password"])
        )
        self._session = self._driver.session()

    def delete_all(self):
        """Delete all nodes and relationships from the graph."""
        self._session.run("MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE n")

    def add_snapshot(self, data):
        """
        Add a snapshot to the Neo4j database.
        
        Args:
            data (dict): The snapshot data to be added.
        """
        snapshot_id = str(uuid.uuid4())  # Generate a unique snapshot ID
        self._session.execute_write(self._add_complete_graph, data, snapshot_id)

    def _create_constraints(self, tx, labels):
        """
        Create uniqueness constraints for the specified labels.
        
        Args:
            tx (neo4j.Transaction): The transaction to be executed.
            labels (list): List of labels for which to create uniqueness constraints.
        """
        for label in labels:
            tx.run(f"CREATE CONSTRAINT IF NOT EXISTS FOR (n:{label}) REQUIRE n.oHash IS UNIQUE")

    @staticmethod
    def _calculate_oHash(node):
        """
        Calculate the oHash for a node based on its properties.

        Args:
            node (dict): The node properties.

        Returns:
            str: The calculated oHash.
        """
        properties = {k: v for k, v in node.items() if k not in ['id', 'snapshotId', 'oHash']}
        properties_json = json.dumps(properties, sort_keys=True)
        return hashlib.md5(properties_json.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

    def _create_or_update_nodes(self, tx, nodes, snapshot_id):
        """
        Create or update nodes in the graph.

        Args:
            tx (neo4j.Transaction): The transaction to be executed.
            nodes (list): The nodes to be created or updated.
            snapshot_id (str): The ID of the snapshot.
        """
        for node in nodes:
            node['oHash'] = self._calculate_oHash(node)
            node['snapshotId'] = snapshot_id
            tx.run("""
                MERGE (n:{0} {{oHash: $oHash}})
                ON CREATE SET n = $props
                ON MATCH SET n = $props
            """.format(node['label']), oHash=node['oHash'], props=node)

    def _create_relationships(self, tx, prev, curr):
        """
        Create relationships between nodes in the graph.

        Args:
            tx (neo4j.Transaction): The transaction to be executed.
            prev (dict): The properties of the previous node.
            curr (dict): The properties of the current node.
        """
        if prev and curr:
            oHashA = self._calculate_oHash(prev)
            oHashB = self._calculate_oHash(curr)
            tx.run("""
                MATCH (a:{0} {{oHash: $oHashA}}), (b:{1} {{oHash: $oHashB}})
                MERGE (a)-[r:HAS_NEXT]->(b)
                ON CREATE SET r.strength = 1
                ON MATCH SET r.strength = r.strength + 1
            """.format(prev['label'], curr['label']), oHashA=oHashA, oHashB=oHashB)

    def _add_complete_graph(self, tx, data, snapshot_id):
        """
        Add a complete graph to the Neo4j database for a given snapshot.

        Args:
            tx (neo4j.Transaction): The transaction to be executed.
            data (dict): The snapshot data.
            snapshot_id (str): The ID of the snapshot.
        """
        nodes = data['nodes']
        self._create_or_update_nodes(tx, nodes, snapshot_id)
        tx.run("""
            MATCH (a {snapshotId: $snapshotId}), (b {snapshotId: $snapshotId})
            WHERE a.oHash < b.oHash
            MERGE (a)-[r:HAS]->(b)
            ON CREATE SET r.strength = 1, r.snapshotId = $snapshotId
            ON MATCH SET r.strength = r.strength + 1
        """, snapshotId=snapshot_id)
        self._create_relationships(tx, data.get('previousMatchSnapshotNode', None), data.get('currentMatchSnapshotNode', None))
```

All input and suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. For everyone who might stumble across this thread here are two things that are wrong with the code.

Firstly, I never close the session. Since I was dealing with GCP Functions I completely forgot about this. I added it to the class destructor:

```
def __del__(self):
    """Close the connection to the Neo4j database."""
    self._session.close()
    self._driver.close()
```

Secondly, I read in the Neo4j Performance Recommendation docs:
https://neo4j.com/docs/python-manual/current/performance/
that not setting the DB name when creating the driver can cause a significant overhead when many queries are being executed which was my situation.

```
self._db_name = "neo4j"
self._session = self._driver.session(database=self._db_name)
```

What I found in the profiler when running `EXPLAIN` is that DB-lookup is a major part in most queries. I usually set the DB name in an SQL-connector and never think twice about it.

Answer (score 1):

Cypher queries seem fine. Not sure how the python driver handles the request, but could it be, that it sends all cypher statements directly? I.e. that you experience long durations because you're not waiting for a single network response, but 10 + 45 = 55 network responses? 1.4s / 55 = 25ms per request.
Also, if you print all cypher statements to the console, copy everything and execute them manually in Neo4j's console, how long is the execution time then?

Btw. you can use the UNWIND keyword to load data and iterate over it. This would reduce the time required for parsing the cypher statement as well reduce the overhead of multiple small requests: https://medium.com/neo4j/5-tips-tricks-for-fast-batched-updates-of-graph-structures-with-neo4j-and-cypher-73c7f693c8cc

Comment: I forgot to mention, I did try to execute it directly in Neo4jBrowser and its in between 0-1ms per connection added. I am working on refactoring to use UNWIND as we speak.

Comment: Is this a Python neo4j driver related issue then?

Comment: Even the delete_all query, MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE n, is 1ms in the browser and through python its approx. 450 ms

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the main issue, but the `MATCH` clause in `_add_complete_graph` does not specify the node label(s) for either `a` or `b`. That prevents the use of any indexes, forcing all nodes to be scanned for each of those nodes.

You must specify node labels in order to use the corresponding indexes.

*By the way, the [label expression syntax](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/expressions/#label-expressions) was enhanced in neo4j 5.0.*

[UPDATE]

If you do not know beforehand the labels of `a` and `b`, there is one workaround. You could add a new label (say, `Snapshot`) to all possible `a` and `b` nodes, and create an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/indexes-for-search-performance/) or [uniqueness constraint](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/constraints/) on `:Snapshot(snapshotId)`.

Comment: This is a good observation. The problem is I don't know which labels they will be beforehand since I send 10 nodes of different labels that all need to be connected with each other. I might need to think of a better solution for this.